# Spring Statemachine: how to get transitions of choice states?

Tags: spring-statemachine

I configure a state machine thusly:

```
    StateMachineTransitionConfigurer transitions = builder.configureTransitions();
    transitions.withChoice().source(CHOICE). //
    first(A, aGuard). //
    then(B, bGuard). //
    last(C);
```

Then, in a different place, I'd like to get the choice transitions from this configuration.  Whereas I can get the choice states easily enough by doing:

```
    for (final State smState : stateMachine.getStates()) {
        if (smState.getPseudoState() != null && smState.getPseudoState().getKind() == PseudoStateKind.CHOICE) {
// smState is a choice state
        }
    }
```

I have no idea how to get the list of transitions from these choice states (the "first", "then"s, and "last" above).

There appears to be no way to access this information.  Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally solved this issue by introspecting the "choices" property of ChoicePseudoState, for which there is no accessor, for some reason:

```
    final Field choicesField = ChoicePseudoState.class.getDeclaredField("choices");
    choicesField.setAccessible(true);

    for (final State<SessionStateType, SessionEvent> smState : stateMachine.getStates()) {
        if (smState.getPseudoState() != null && smState.getPseudoState().getKind() == PseudoStateKind.CHOICE) {
            final ChoicePseudoState<SessionStateType, SessionEvent> choice = ((ChoicePseudoState<SessionStateType, SessionEvent>) smState
                .getPseudoState());
            final List<ChoiceStateData<SessionStateType, SessionEvent>> choices = (List<ChoiceStateData<SessionStateType, SessionEvent>>) choicesField
                .get(choice);

...
```

Comment: I'm must making other fixes for these classes and was wondering why you need to access this info. It was intentionally left so that there's no direct access(once we add it, we need to live with it). So just asking if there is a better way to get what you need from somewhere else?

Comment: The reason is to extract the state machine's configuration in order to generate a state transition graph (in this particular case, using this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_%28graph_description_language%29 )

Answer (score 1):

State machine has:

```
Collection<Transition<S,E>> getTransitions()
```

and from `Transition` you need to check source or target

```
State<S,E> getSource();
State<S,E> getTarget()
```

Comment: Sorry, but the transitions from choice pseudo-states are not available via getTransitions().  I only have the transitions from normal, non-peusdo-states.

Comment: Ah sorry I misunderstood what you asked. Lemmy see if we can just expose that internal data for next release.

Answer (score -1):

```
var possibleEnentsForCurrentState = stateMachine.getTransitions().stream()
        .filter(t -> t.getSource().equals(stateMachine.getState()))
        .map(t -> t.getTrigger().getEvent())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?